# How to compare a fixed java array and a dynamic one?

Tags: java, arrays

I am developing a tuition management system that is focused on adding subjects for the tuition . It is more focused for the tuition staff. I have set a fixed array of students which is around 20 and I want to compare that array with a dynamic list of subjects array to get the number of students under a particular teacher.
Unfortunately both arrays obviously has different sizes so how do I loop through it?

```
public void checknumberofstudents()
{

        for (int i = 0; i < ChooseStudent.suboptions.size(); i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(data.get(i).collectionz.size());
            if  (data.get(i).collectionz.get(i).getTeacher() == ChooseStudent.suboptions.get(i).getTeacher())
                noofteachers[i]++;
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error with the teacher array");
            }
        }


    }
```

- data is a fixed list of students.Each student has their own collection
  of subjects.So i get the index of a particular student then get a
  particular subject under his/her collection then get the teacher name
  so I can match it with the dynamically allocted subjects arrray's
  teachers. Then I will update the noofteachers array so I can get the
  number of students under a particular teacher.

It is a big project with a lot of code so I don't think so it's appropriate to share it here. Here is a link to my github for the whole project.
https://github.com/ariff20/UPSR

Comment: You should use sql query instead of doing this kind of query by programmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, the following code should work

```
    public Map<String, Integer> studentsByTeacherCount(ObservableList<Student> data) {

    Map<String, Integer> teacherMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Student student = data.get(i);
        List<Subject> subjectList = student.getCollectionz();
        for(Subject subject: subjectList) {
            Integer entry = teacherMap.get(subject.getTeacher());
            if(entry == null) {
                teacherMap.put(subject.getTeacher(), Integer.valueOf(1));
            } else {
                teacherMap.put(subject.getTeacher(), entry + 1);
            }
        }

    }

    return teacherMap;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have not learned about Java maps in my oop class. To my understanding , this will return a map with a string key and an int value ? So the string is the teacher's name and the int is the number of students under him/her?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You can read up java doc API for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Make your comparison code independent of the array sizes.

In other words, map the occurrence of ***elements*** inside the smaller array to their occurrence in the bigger one, traversing both entirely and independently of each-other.

When you have the map, you can know whether all elements of the smaller array are found within the bigger array, and, in reverse, even which elements the bigger array has, and the smaller one doesn't.